# Cant encrypt using JHipster Registry UI

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

Seems pretty simple, I setup the REGISTRY_KEY using environment variables and am running JHister Registry from the generated jhipster_registry.yml.

[image]

Then, I login and navigate over to the encryption UI, enter my secret and hit 'encrypt'...

[image]

Where am I going wrong, or is the JHipsterRegistry wrong?

Comment: What do you see in browser's console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to encrypt/decrypt succeeds, but the Angular client throws an error when trying to parse the response as JSON, since the response is actually a string.

This was reported in [this issue](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/issues/434), and fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/commit/d9edb43f1be4ad587678c9e6715aa705c840f275).

You can build the master branch of [JHipster Registry](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry), or wait for a new release to use the UI to encrypt/decrypt.